# Change BGR image color using a mask?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

[image]I have a BGR image and 3 binary masks. What I want is to change the color on the BGR image applying these masks. By this, I mean that if pixels [3][3] and [4][4] on the mask are ones (white color), the pixels [3][3] and [4][4] on the image will be blue color (for example).

I'd like to know if there is a way that avoids using loops with if-then-else sentences. I know how to do this.

The image you are seeing is the output I want. The blue, red and green are 3 different masks that have been pasted into the original image. They are BINARY images, so they are originally black and white masks.

This is the code I'm doing to get this image done:

```
row = 0
while row < height:
    column = 0
    while column < width:
        if true_positives_mask[row][column] != 0:
            original_image[row][column] = constants.GREEN
        elif false_positives_mask[row][column] != 0:
            original_image[row][column] = constants.BLUE
        elif true_negatives_mask[row][column] != 0:
            original_image[row][column] = constants.RED
        column += 1
    row += 1

return original_image
```

Comment: create a full size image of each color, then use python's equivalent of openCV's .copyTo(mat, mask) function for each of your masks and corresponding color image.

Comment: I've found a solution searching about that. Thank you.

Comment: @deko If you answered your own question in a way that is satisfactory to you, you should probably post is an answer and not an edit to the question.

Comment: Agree, I was looking before for that option but couldn't find it so I had given up.

Found it now.

Answer (score 0):

Way faster solution that I've come across:

```
# True positives coordinates
coordinates = numpy.where(true_positives_mask != 0)
original_image[coordinates[0], coordinates[1]] = constants.GREEN
# False positives coordinates
coordinates = numpy.where(false_positives_mask != 0)
original_image[coordinates[0], coordinates[1]] = constants.BLUE
# False negatives coordinates
coordinates = numpy.where(false_negatives_mask != 0)
original_image[coordinates[0], coordinates[1]] = constants.RED

return original_image
```